# Managing component state in NativeScript-Vue ListView

Tags: listview, nativescript-vue

I am having problems with managing component state in NativeScript-Vue ListView. I am having the exact same problem explained in the following article : https://www.nativescript.org/blog/managing-component-state-in-nativescript-listview. The article does not explains the solution for Nativescript-Vue. I am using Switch components in my ListView to keep the list items state if they are selected or not, but no way. Is there anyone faced the same problem and applied the solution in the article for NativeScript-Vue?

Answer (score 0):

It's actually pretty easy to fix. Since a listview reuses components we shouldn't set data inside the component itself. What we should do is add/change the data inside the object in the array so the listview can properly update the items.

You can add a event that triggers on the parent to update the list on switch changed do this via a tap since the switch on changed event will get triggered by every rerender/reuse of component in listview.
This is a bit hard to manage but does work.

```
<Template>
  <StackLayout @tap="onSwitchTapped" orientation="horizontal">
     <Switch :isUserInteractionEnabled="false" v-model="item.isActive"/>
  </StackLayout>
</Template>
<Script>
   export default {
      props: {
           item: null,
           onItemUpdated: null
      }
      methods: {
         onSwitchTapped()
         {
             this.item.isActive = !this.item.isActive;
             if(onItemUpdated != null)
                onItemUpdated(this.item);
         }
      }
   }
</Script>

<Template>
    <ListView for="item in array">
        <component :item="item" :onItemUpdated="onItemUpdated"/>
    </ListView>
</Template>

<Script>
   export default {
       onItemUpdated(item) {
          this.array[item.index] = item;
       }
   }
</Script>
```

You can also remove the switch and add a itemTap on the listview and then setting the data in the list:

```
<ListView for="item in array" @itemTap="itemTapped">

itemTapped(evt) {
    this.array[evt.index].VARIABLE = true/false;
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution and it did not work especially when I try to update the status with "checkedChange" event. Because when I scroll the list many of the Switch elements trigger the "checkedChange" event and app tries to update the list elements status by making apiCalls to the backed. So, everything messed up. I did not understand that why they fires "checkedChange" event. Because in my opinion they should only fire that event when the user tapped on it. Otherwise it is completely useless. So, I dropped using "checkedChange" and used "tap" event. Now everything works as expected.

Comment: @kempo Oh I see hmmm I think this is because the boolean is being set by the ListView and so it should trigger checkedChange everytime a new item is visible in the list(getting reused so resets all variables).

Comment: @kempo I edited the answer to explain the checkedChange problem. Since it is working for you could you check my answer as correct for future users that may have the same issue as you?

Comment: Actually it is not easy to try at the moment because I need to use switch component and I finished this part. If you give me a solution with switch component, I appreciate to try.

Comment: @kempo Edited the answer again please check if this works for you.